# Formal way to perform an "onchange" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jquery for the first time and I cannot get any examples for "onchange" actions to work.

Can someone explain the most basic and formal way to perform an "onchange" action using jquery.  Here's my stats:

**JQUERY VERSION**

```
$().jquery
"1.7.2"
```

**Example Activity That I Can't Get To Work**

https://jsfiddle.net/k27pgkmr/

**My jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hostnameList").on("change", function() {
    contents = $('#hostnameList').val();
    $("#Names").html(contents);
}); });
```

**GOAL:**

Have things happen when I select something from my dropdown menu.

What's the most graceful way to do this?

Comment: You don't have jQuery linked in.  See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k27pgkmr/3/).

Comment: Your example is fine, you just need to add jQuery to the Fiddle. Click the gear icon in the JavaScript pane and select a version of jQuery under Frameworks & Extensions.

Comment: Okay, it seems to also fail when I set the fiddle to 1.7.2, but if I set my jquery to 1.9.1 it works. I guess I better update.

Comment: It should work with 1.7.2, but not earlier versions. `.on()` was added in 1.7.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't have a selection for 1.7.2 any more. How did you set that?

Comment: @barmar that version is from the google chrome console on the machine that I am developing my code on. I provided the jsfiddle as a way to help see the problem that I was experiencing on my machine. In the fiddle, I set my version to prototype 1.7.2 and it did not work. It did work when I set it to jquery 1.9.1, so I'm attempting to upgrade the jquery version on Debian Stretch to 1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code, but in your fiddle. You forgot to reference the jQuery lib. Also, I have set your fiddle to wrap the javascript in the `<head>` since you're already binding it to the `$(document).ready()`.

[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k27pgkmr/2/)